# Why mockgen generates all interfaces in file?

Tags: go

I have a package with interfaces

```golang
package worker

import "context"

//go:generate mockgen -source interfaces.go -destination mock-interfaces.go -package worker Doer

type (
    Doer interface {
        Do(ctx context.Context) error
    }

    LazyThing interface {
        Rest(ctx context.Context) error
    }
)
```

I assumed that mock class will be generated for `Doer` interface only. But I always get mocks for both.

How can I limit the list of processed interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `-source interfaces.go` in the command, you are enabling the source mode of the generator.

You need to provide the form which imports the symbol `Doer` from the fully-qualified package name

Something like:

```
//go:generate mockgen -package worker -destination mock-interfaces.go github.com/yourhandle/worker Doer
```

Then it should pick only that symbol from the package and not all of them.